# how can i remove the value from a DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable, value-type

i have an existing DateTime? object that has a datetime in it.  I want to remove the datetime value from it so when you ask "HasValue" it returns false?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**`Nullable<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)is immutable, so you will have to reassign the variable to a different value to be able to change / remove the underlying value. This makes sense since it is a value-type (although a *special* one at that); value-types are *normally* immutable in the framework. You will notice that neither the`Value`nor the`HasValue` property for`Nullable<T>`has a setter.

```
DateTime? nullableDt = DateTime.Now; 
Console.WriteLine(nullableDt.HasValue); //true

nullableDt = null; 
Console.WriteLine(nullableDt.HasValue); //false
```

or

```
nullableDt = new DateTime?();
```

Comment: @David, post a comment before (or instead of) changing someone's wording? Particularly on a fresh answer. Don't take the wiki thing too far. If you have an issue with someone's phrasing, mention it, give them a chance to fix it or explain it.

Comment: @Anthony I just highlighted the code block and hit the "code" button. Not sure what happened there.

Comment: It's fine, probably some sort of merging issue; I was in the middle of editing it. No offence taken anyway. Cheers.

Comment: @David, ah. Well. Now we see why the world is shaped like a banana.

Answer (score 5):

Set it to null.

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
DateTime? value = DateTime.Now;
```

then call

```
value = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set it back to null?

```
  DateTime? d = null;

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HasValue1 = {0}", d.HasValue); //False

  d = DateTime.Now;

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HasValue2 = {0}", d.HasValue); //True

  d = null;

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HasValue3 = {0}", d.HasValue); //False
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable itself cannot be null, though you can set the minValue, it is an equivalent to '1/1/0001 00:00:00'

```
DateTime dvar = DateTime.MinValue;
```